# "MSB6004" Error When Debugging an ASP.NET Core Project by VS Code in Ubuntu

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, razor-pages

When I try to debbuging my ASP.NET Core project by VS Code in Ubuntu 19.04 I face with the following error:

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.100/Roslyn/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(59,5): error MSB6004: The specified task executable location "/" is invalid. [/home/ubuntu/Test/Test.csproj]
```

What does it mean?

Comment: You could see [here](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed Ubuntu 19.10, and now I can use .NET Core SDK without any problem. Also I have opened an issue related to this problem on GitHub with [this link](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/3987)